# Should I implement hResume microformat for my CV?

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, microformats

I am revamping my site and making it more Google friendly. I have implemented a few rich snippets already and now wondering whether it's worthy enough to make my online resume `hResume` compatible to be available on Google in better shape?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any documentation from Google about it?

Comment: @unor Google encouraging Schema and microformats

Comment: Do you have a link? I know that Google supported Microformats some years ago, but since Schema.org, they seem to support only JSON-LD & Microdata & RDFa for their Rich Snippets, at least according to their documentation I could find.

Comment: @unor You are right. Right now no rich snippet for Resume.

Comment: Based on your last comment, it appears this question is now considered complete so it's being closed.